# Capybara: make sure that a link is hidden after an AJAX request without testing the implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm a bit unsure about this. Here's my spec:

```
it 'hides the "Load more" link when the last page is reached', js: true, focus: true do
  within "table.#{model.model_name.underscore.pluralize}" do
    click_link 'Mehr laden'
  end

  page.should have_selector('.load_more a', visible: false)
end
```

This works, but I'm actually testing the implementation, which is not good practice. So I rewrote the spec like this:

```
it 'hides the "Load more" link when the last page is reached', js: true, focus: true do
  within "table.#{model.model_name.underscore.pluralize}" do
    click_link 'Mehr laden'
  end

  find_link("Mehr laden").should_not be_visible
end
```

But sadly, `find_link` does not wait for the AJAX request to complete, so it fails. If I put a `sleep 1` in front of it, it works.

How can I tell `find_link` to wait (like `has_selector?`)? I don't want to change any global configuration for this, and `wait_until` will be deprecated in Capybara 2.

Thanks a lot for help,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

The solution actually is pretty easy:

page.should have_link('Mehr laden', visible: false)

Didn't know one can use `visible: true|false` on `have_link`. Nice to know.

**Update**

I don't know if this is generally true, but I've come to the opinion that you should try to always only use the `have_XXX` matchers if possible and **not** methods like `find()` or `all()` as the earlier ones wait for content to appear, while the later ones don't.